# Using source with gdb command

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I can write gdbscript and load it yo gdb with

```
source my_script
```

In my_script I write some breakpoint etc.

How can I load that script in the command line that I run gdb?

```
gdb -p `pidof my_process`
```

Comment: Try [`-x my_script`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html#index-_002d_002dcommand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary commands like so:

```
gdb -ex 'break main' -ex 'source foo' -ex 'set confirm off' -p $pid
```

If your commands are already in a file, do this:

```
gdb -x my_script -p $PID`
```